# Adding data to a property of type List<>

Tags: c#, collections

I am extracting data from an excel sheet and placing that into class properties. 
In the below shown piece of code I am trying to add data into a property of type `List<>`.  It executes without errors but the `List<>` count is 1 all the time. 
as shown in the below example the for loop runs 5 times but the rah.rahTermDate count is 1 after existing the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {                  
    RawACAHireTermDates rahd = new RawACAHireTermDates();
    rahd.RawHireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, k], j), workbookPart, false, true));
    rahd.RawTermDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, (k + 1)], j), workbookPart, false, true));
    rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates> { rahd };
    //  rah.rahTermDate.Add(rahd);               
  }
```

Business object :

```
public class MasterClientGroupSheetData
    {
    public class RawACAHireTermDates
    {     
        public DateTime? RawHireDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RawTermDate { get; set; }                   
    }

    public class RawACAHireTermEmployee
    {
 ...........
        public List<RawACAHireTermDates> rahTermDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates> { rahd };
```

Every time the loop runs, you are setting a NEW list to `rah.rahTermDate`.

Your code should be more like this:

```
//before the loop, declare a new List
rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {                  
    RawACAHireTermDates rahd = new RawACAHireTermDates();
    rahd.RawHireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, k], j), workbookPart, false, true));
    rahd.RawTermDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, (k + 1)], j), workbookPart, false, true));

    //add to the existing list...
    rah.rahTermDate.Add(rahd);               
  }
```

Comment: All of the answers are correct. But I can mark only one as answer (:

Answer (score 5):

This code is re-initializing your List on each iteration and losing the previous data.

`rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates> { rahd };`

You should define your list outside of the `for` loop, and then add items to it using `.add()`

Answer (score 3):

You are recreating your list in the loop. Create it outside the loop once:

```
rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{                  
    RawACAHireTermDates rahd = new RawACAHireTermDates();
    rahd.RawHireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, k], j), workbookPart, false, true));
    rahd.RawTermDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetCellValue(GetCell(sheetData, Cells[i, (k + 1)], j), workbookPart, false, true));
    rah.rahTermDate.Add(rahd);
    // rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates> { rahd }; <-- this line was the problem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create new list every iteration

`rah.rahTermDate = new List<RawACAHireTermDates> { rahd };`

which contains only one item, which was processed the same iteration.
To fix this problem define list outside for loop, in loop add elements to the list and assign `rah.rahTermDate` after for loop.